# How to access first item in hash value array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash whose value is an array of song lyrics (line1, line2, etc..)

Code:

```
class Song
    def initialize(lyrics)
       @lyrics = lyrics 
    end
    def get_song_name()
        puts @lyrics.keys
    end
    def get_first_line()
        puts @lyrics.values[0]
    end
end

wasted = Song.new({"Wasted" => ["I like us better when we're wasted",
    "It makes it easier to see"]})

real_world = Song.new("Real World" => ["Straight up what do you want to learn about here", "if i was someone else would this all fall apart"])

wasted.get_song_name()
wasted.get_first_line()
#=>I like us better when we're wasted
#=>It makes it easuer to see
```

So when I called `wasted.get_first_line`, I want it to get the first item in the array of the value. I tried doing `@lyrics.values[0]`, but it returns both lines of the song instead of the first one.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `@lyrics.values.first.first`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to understand that in the above code `@lyrics` is a Hash. Here is what you are doing and what it translates to:

```
@lyrics
# => {"Wasted"=>["I like us better when we're wasted", "It makes it easier to see"]} 


@lyrics.values
# => [["I like us better when we're wasted", "It makes it easier to see"]] 

@lyrics.values[0]
# => ["I like us better when we're wasted", "It makes it easier to see"] 

@lyrics.values[0][0]

# => "I like us better when we're wasted"
```

Therefore to access the first line, you need to get the first element of the values array. i.e.

```
@lyrics.values[0][0]
```

or

```
@lyrics.values.first.first
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets use this hash for example:

```
x = {foo: [:bar, :baz]}

x.values             # => [[:bar, :baz]]
x.values.first       # => [:bar, :baz]
x.values.first.first # => :bar
```

In other words, `@lyrics.values[0]` will return the first value in the `@lyrics` hash, which is the array of two songs. You still have to get the first song out of that array.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer to original question, but if I were you, I would modify the class like below.  It will be more apt to store song name and lines of lyrics as individual attributes, instead of merging them as a hash - which kind of defies the whole purpose of having `Song` class.

```
class Song
    attr_accessor :song_name, :lyrics

    def initialize(song_name, lyrics)
       @song_name = song_name
       @lyrics = lyrics 
    end
end
```

Please note that you may not need `get_first_line` method.  You could always use [`Array#first`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) to have same effect:

```
real_world = Song.new("Real World", ["Line 1", "Line 2"])
puts real_world.lyrics.first # Prints "Line 1"
```

You can also access lyrics lines using array index

```
puts real_world.lyrics[1] # Prints "Line 2"
```

Comment: Good idea! Just changed it to this setup. I was only using the last one as a way to practice hashes.